# I am unable to read multiple rows from xlsx file

Tags: node.js, promise, ftp, xlsx

I am trying to read multiple rows from xlsx file. My xlsx sheet contains various details one of which is an FTP directory, password detail.
Each row contains a different FTP directory.
I am able to read, fetch and retrieve the data from FTP if only one row is mentioned in the sheet
but as soon as I add an extra row to be read it starts showing promise error,
**Below is my code**
dataJson1 is the excel sheet(JSON)

````
for (let i = 0; i < dataJson1.length; i++) {

        dir = dataJson1[i]['FTP DIR'];
        subfolder = dataJson1[i]['Sub Folder'];
        ftpPath = dir + subfolder;
        host = dataJson1[i]['FTP IP'];
        user = dataJson1[i]['FTP Username'];
        password = dataJson1[i]['FTP Password'];
        ticketStatus = dataJson1[i]['Status']
        console.log("FTP LOCATION:" + ftpPath + "\n" + "HOSTNAME:" + host + "\n" + "USERNAME:" + user + "\n" + "PASSWORD:" + password + "\n")
        //Reading the list of directories present in the FTP location
        console.log("value of i" + i);
        ///////////
        if (ticketStatus == true) {
            if (!ftp) {
                ftp = new PromiseFtp();
            }
            const ftpPromise = ftp.connect({
                host: host, user: user,
                password: password
            }).then(function (serverMessage) {
                console.log('Server message: ' + serverMessage)
                //console.log("value of i" + i)

                return ftp.list(ftpPath);

            }).then(function (list) {
                console.log('Directory listing:');

                var dirList = (list)
                console.log(dirList)

                console.log("Number of directories:" + dirList.length)


                var jsondirString = JSON.stringify(dirList)
                var datadirJson1 = JSON.parse(jsondirString)
                for (var j = 0; j < dirList.length; j++) {

                    //console.log(datadirJson1[j]['name'])
                    ticketName.push(datadirJson1[j]['name'])
                    //console.log(ftpTime)
                    ftpTime.push(datadirJson1[j]['date'])
                }
                return ftp.end();
            });
            promises.push(ftpPromise)
        }//status check ends

    }//Loop ends here


  Promise.all(promises).then(arrayOfResults => {

        console.log(ticketName);
        var ticketNameArr = [];


        for (let i = 0; i < ticketName.length; i++) {
            let ticketNameIs = ticketName[i];
            let ftpTimeIs = ftpTime[i]
            let ticketDetail = ticketApp(ticketNameIs, ftpTimeIs);
            Promise.all(ticketDetail).then(function (values) {
                //console.log(values);
                ticketNameArr.push({
                    // FtpTime: values[0].ftpTime,
                    Date: values[0].ftpTime,
                    TicketName: ticketNameIs,
                    //Add Dynamic folder column----
                    In_Input_Location: values[0].ticketStatusInput,
                    Input_Time: values[0].mtime,
                    In_Result_Location: values[1].ticketStatusResult,
                    Result_Time: values[1].mtime,
                    //Will help in preparing comments
                    CallAPi: values[3].apiStatus,
                    ReportStatus: values[3].reportStatus,
                    Comment: values[4].Comment,
                    Status: values[5].ticketStatus
                    // LogStatus: values[2].logStatus,
                    // LogCreateTime: values[2].birthtime,
                    // LogModifiedTime: values[2].mtime,


                });


                if (ticketNameArr.length == ticketName.length) {


                    //uncomment below command if sheet is blank then comment back
                    // ws = XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(ws, ticketNameArr,{origin:0, skipHeader:false});
                    //comment below command if sheet is blank then uncomment

                    ws = XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(ws, ticketNameArr, { origin: -1, skipHeader: true });

                    //                  
                    let wsRemDup = removeDuplicate(ws)

                    console.log("Unique Data", wsRemDup)
                    //OverWriting Unique data

                    wb.Sheets[first_sheet_name] = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(wsRemDup);
                    XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'DailyTicketSatus.xlsx')





                    // respond.render('result', { "ticketNameArr": ticketNameArr });
                    respond.render('index', { "ticketNameArr": ticketNameArr });




                }


            });

        }


    })



})```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the async/await syntax for this task, it's easier to read and you can ensure that the ftp.end() call is complete before proceeding to the next ftp host. This is probably the reason why the original code is failing to process more than one row.

```
async function runFTPJob(dataJson1) {

    let promises = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < dataJson1.length; i++) {

        dir = dataJson1[i]['FTP DIR'];
        subfolder = dataJson1[i]['Sub Folder'];
        ftpPath = dir + subfolder;
        host = dataJson1[i]['FTP IP'];
        user = dataJson1[i]['FTP Username'];
        password = dataJson1[i]['FTP Password'];
        ticketStatus = dataJson1[i]['Status']
        console.log("Getting row:", i);
        console.log("FTP LOCATION:" + ftpPath + "\n" + "HOSTNAME:" + host + "\n" + "USERNAME:" + user + "\n" + "PASSWORD:" + password + "\n")
        //Reading the list of directories present in the FTP location

        if (ticketStatus == true) {
            if (!ftp) {
                ftp = new PromiseFtp();
            }

            try { 
                let ftpPromise = ftp.connect({ host, user, password });
                promises.push(ftpPromise);
                let serverMessage = await ftpPromise;
                console.log('Server message: ' + serverMessage)
                let dirList = await ftp.list(ftpPath);
                console.log('Directory listing:', dirList);
                console.log("Number of directories:" + dirList.length)
                for (let dirEntry of dirList) {
                    ticketName.push(dirEntry.name);
                    ftpTime.push(dirEntry.date);
                }
                await ftp.end();
            } catch (e) {
                console.error("An error occurred accessing ftp site:", e.message);
            }
        }//status check ends
    }//Loop ends here``

    return promises;
}


function processTickets() {

    console.log(ticketName);
    var ticketNameArr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < ticketName.length; i++) {
        let ticketNameIs = ticketName[i];
        let ftpTimeIs = ftpTime[i]
        let ticketDetail = ticketApp(ticketNameIs, ftpTimeIs);
        Promise.all(ticketDetail).then(function (values) {
            //console.log(values);
            ticketNameArr.push({
                // FtpTime: values[0].ftpTime,
                Date: values[0].ftpTime,
                TicketName: ticketNameIs,
                //Add Dynamic folder column----
                In_Input_Location: values[0].ticketStatusInput,
                Input_Time: values[0].mtime,
                In_Result_Location: values[1].ticketStatusResult,
                Result_Time: values[1].mtime,
                //Will help in preparing comments
                CallAPi: values[3].apiStatus,
                ReportStatus: values[3].reportStatus,
                Comment: values[4].Comment,
                Status: values[5].ticketStatus
                // LogStatus: values[2].logStatus,
                // LogCreateTime: values[2].birthtime,
                // LogModifiedTime: values[2].mtime,


            });


            if (ticketNameArr.length == ticketName.length) {


                //uncomment below command if sheet is blank then comment back
                // ws = XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(ws, ticketNameArr,{origin:0, skipHeader:false});
                //comment below command if sheet is blank then uncomment

                ws = XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(ws, ticketNameArr, { origin: -1, skipHeader: true });

                //                  
                let wsRemDup = removeDuplicate(ws)

                console.log("Unique Data", wsRemDup)
                //OverWriting Unique data

                wb.Sheets[first_sheet_name] = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(wsRemDup);
                XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'DailyTicketSatus.xlsx')

                // respond.render('result', { "ticketNameArr": ticketNameArr });
                respond.render('index', { "ticketNameArr": ticketNameArr });

            }
        });
    }
}

( async() => {
    await runFTPJob(dataJson1);
    processTickets();
})();
```

Comment: I was able to read the two rows but as you can see earlier I was keeping array of promise which was going to be passed in another function. How can I do that now?

Comment: I've updated the answer to return a list of promises from the runFTPJob function, this will return all the promises from ftp.connect...

Comment: I have updated my code in question so that it clarifies what it was trying to do next.I am not getting where promiseList will be used then.

Comment: Oh yes, I see, I've updated the answer to reflect this. We'll await for runFTPJob to complete, then run the processTickets() function. This is essentially what you were doing before.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I was stuck on this particular issue since last 2 weeks.

Comment: You're very welcome,  glad to be of help! I wish you a successful project!

Comment: If possible can you explain me what was the issue with my original code?

Comment: I believe the main issue was that you were calling ftp.connect repeatedly without waiting for the ftp.end() function to complete. This was causing the promise-ftp package to give an error and effectively stop working for that session. By calling await ftp.end(), the loop can continue.